Word/phrase to describe this "circular" logic?
Let's say I am unintentionally competing with my friend in a game, and we both are arguing.

I say I am not competing with you. (I say it defensively)


My friend says you couldn't if you were trying to. (Basically you can't compete with me -- to that I say I am not even trying to compete with you -- to that he says you can't even if you try to.)

Basically, the above two phrases/arguments are translation from my native language.
I think the argument feels circular to me (for the lack of a better word).
I can't think of word/phrase to describe this situation.

The situation you describe could be characterized as your talking past one another or even as having two separate conversations. Both of these characterizations get at the fact that neither of you addressed the other’s point. Your own point was about your intentions, whereas your friend’s point was about your abilities.
A third characterization, one that focuses on the on the exchange’s cyclical (which is to say, seemingly endlessly repeating) nature, is to say that together the two of you sounded like a broken record. Here the metaphor involves a scratched (not necessarily cracked) phonograph record whose flaw causes the needle to jump and then land back at an earlier spot,  thus resulting in an audio infinite loop.

Of course, if your interaction were to gain notoriety as, say, the longest-known example of fruitless verbal exchange,  and if that status were  acknowledged  by causing a replacement in The Guinness Book, then that really would be a broken record.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at%20cross-purposes

On the basis of a broken long jump record, that protracted "non-interaction" would be a broken broken record record :)

We could consider argument without end.

The Dutch historian Pieter Geyl (died in 1966) coined the phrase “argument without end” to get at the constant reappearance of old arguments or viewpoints. [emphasis added]

Though cited in the article are major topics, and old points may recur at different time after some past discussions, this phrase should be usable in others like the OP’s example.

I am not even trying to compete with you.


You can't even if you try to.


...


Friend, let’s end this argument without end.

